# Expo Router - preserve state of screen when pushing a new one

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I'm working with Expo Router in React Native. I'm noticing that when I use router.back() the previous screen is not keeping it's old state, it just re-renders.

Example:

```
export default ScreenA = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // This is executed again when going back.
  }, [])

  return <Link href="screen-b">Screen B</Link>

}

export default ScreenB = () => {

  const router = useRouter();
  return <Pressable onPress={() => router.back()}>Screen A</Pressable>

}
```

Is there any solution to this?
I've thought about moving some parts of the state to redux, but is there anything simpler? Should I move to React Navigation?

Comment: My temporary short-term solution was to add extra data to an app store ([redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) in this case) and use that to recreate the screen's state when going back, it was an ugly solution. My longer term solution was moving to [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) which didn't have that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at my comment in the github issue here:
https://github.com/expo/router/issues/460#issuecomment-1973959243

I think the solution is:
In your _layout, replace the `Slot` with `Tabs` like below.

```js
import { Link, Slot, Stack } from 'expo-router'
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router/tabs'

                  {/* <Slot /> */}
                  {/* <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} /> */}
                 <Tabs
                    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                      headerShown: false,
                      tabBarStyle: {
                        // display: route.name === 'example' ? 'none' : 'flex',
                        display: 'none',
                      },
                    })}
                  />
```

The result will be similar to using `Tab Navigation` of the react-navigation.
In Tab Navigation it displays the route again (if mouted previously) without reloading/rerendering it.
It will use the previously rendered version of that route.

Comparing the different route rendering methods:

- `Slot` always reloads the routes.
- `Stack` can display without reloading, however that only occurs in some certain circumstances for routes which are currently in the stack based on the LILO rules.
- So finally, we can use `Tabs` but just hide the header and the tab navigator menu. This will always use the previously rendered version of that route. Never reload.